# Angular CLI create .spec files for already existing components

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-unit-test

There is an option in `.angular-cli.json` to disable the automatic creating of `*.spec` files e.g. for components, see [json schema](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/398356503ab4729cf40587804c44b55eb5c99768/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L318-L353).

This is a really nice feature because personally (this is just my opinion) testing the components might not be the thing that really worth it in a fast growing project.

However sometimes I would like to have an option to generate / recreate the corresponding `*.spec` file for an already existing component / service / pipe / whatsoever.

Is that possible using some command line call?

Created a [feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7727), let's see how it goes...

Comment: Tests are important in a fast growing project ! When it will be a big project you will suffer from side effects problems and it will become a slow growing project. QED

Comment: You are right. Might be that I just expressed it wrong: when requirements are not yet clear and the project is in proof of concept state the tests are a real problem. That's why it is good to be able to generate them a bit later :)

Comment: you can easily use Angular spec generator extension in VS Code. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ThorstenRintelen.angular-spec-generator#:~:text=Angular%20spec%20(jest%20%2F%20jasmine%20%2F%20mockito)%20file%20generator&text=Select%20an%20Angular%20*.,component

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Currently Angular CLI does not provide this functionality and it is not clear how and when it will be possible to manage it in official way.

However, [here is a library "ngx-spec" that generates the spec based on Angular CLI spec presets](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-spec).

If you are using vsCode the authors of ngx-spec recomend using this extension
https://github.com/cyrilletuzi/vscode-angular-schematics

Answer (score 32):

chose a directory where you want to generate spec, and then it will generate all Angular spec.

only generate file when spec file not exist, and the component / directive / guard / pipe / service follow the angular-cli file generate name.

```
npm install -g angular-spec-generator

angular-spec-generator 'C:\Users\Alan\Desktop\test'
```

Answer (score 12):

Scaffolding for existing .ts files can be created by using https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-spec

To install in an Angular project:

`npm i -D ngx-spec@^2.0.0`

(-D is the shorthand for --save-dev)

example usage (for a service):

`ng g ngx-spec:spec path/my.service`

or

`ng g ngx-spec:spec path/my.service.ts`

For a service, this doesn’t set up a test to be created via injection. Adapt so that the test looks something like this:

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';

describe('DataService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DataService, AuthService, HttpClient, HttpHandler
      ]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([DataService, AuthService], (service: DataService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
});
```

It's also meant to be possible to generate tests using a wildcard, e.g.

`ng g ngx-specs '**/*`

That didn't work for me - see the GitHub issue:

https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-spec/issues/10

---

**Note** - As a strategy to implement test-driven development, I found it easiest to search for and remove all existing `*.spec.ts` files that had automatically been created in the Angular project as part of initial artifact creation (by searching in Windows explorer), then as a starting point I created a single test for the main Angular data provider service, using `ngx-spec`

Answer (score -4):

There are 2 solutions for this :

- **1 :** Create a copy of `@angular/cli`, add your own code (or extend it) to the existing `ng new` command (https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40angular/cli/commands/new.ts) and integrate to your global installed `@angular/cli`. This is probably impractical and not worth your time.
- **2 :** Make a pull request to the `@angular/cli` team to integrate your idea, and if the code works and the idea seems good enough, they might add it.