# How to create only spec.ts file with Angular CLI?

Tags: angular

I was creating the Angular component with `--spec=false` but now I need to do unit test, is there a way to create only `spec.ts files` with Angular CLI?

Comment: dont think you have special command for this, but it very easy to add such file manually

Comment: Yes I can do it manually, but I want to know if there is a command for this... =D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular CLI create .spec files for already existing components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276055/angular-cli-create-spec-files-for-already-existing-components)

Answer (score 5):

Currently, Angular CLI does not provide this functionality. However, you can make a pull request to the @angular/cli team to integrate your idea, and if the code works and the idea seems good enough, they might add it.

Or, you can use [SimonTest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SimonTest.simontest) is an extension to VS Code that generates tests for existing files.

Comment: Yes. SimonTest is the app for creating a spec.ts file within an existing component folder.

Comment: Tried a number of alternative spec creators and SimonTest was the only one that took an existing Component and generated a functional spec file with all the required imports, declarations, providers etc

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Feature Request](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6584), it has not been implemented at this time.
I think you have to do it by hand for now.