# Is it possible to generate a .spec file for already generated component in angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I understand that `angular-cli` by default creates a `.spec` file for any component we create through it. But, by any chance is it possible to generate only the `.spec` file if one is deleted mistakenly.

I tried some one suggestion -

`ng g c <component_name> --spec-only` but it doesn't work.

Note - Without using any other npm modules (if available).

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46276055/angular-cli-create-spec-files-for-already-existing-components

Comment: its already issue : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7727

Comment: @PranayRana, Yeah I looked at it but then kind of felt if there is a solution probably. Believe, it's not.

Comment: i think if you follow the git, you might get answer

Answer (score 2):

** UPDATE Jul 2018 **
There is now a 3rd party library that reportedly solves this issue [here](https://github.com/smnbbrv/ngx-spec).

**NOTE - original answer **

This is a workaround that will create the .spec file as it WOULD have been created when you first generated the component. So it won't regenerate the exact file you mistakenly deleted, only the original version.

The `ng c` command only creates boilerplate code, so you can use it by doing a workaround, but it will only create the 'virgin boilerplate' of a new component. To do that you first need to go into a **different** folder (eg. create a new folder somewhere else, which you can delete afterwards) and then run the same command.

```
ng g c <component_name>
```

Delete all the files except the spec file, then copy the spec file to the original components folder and update the paths in the generate script to the correct depth (../ etc)

Comment: awesome answer - the linked lib works amazingly well - creates all missing spec files perfectly with just one command